# Calculating the number of boxes that can fit into the back of a truck

Tags: javascript, math

This code calculates the number of boxes that can fit into the back of a truck. All of the dimensions are user defined and the answer is rounded to the nearest whole number. I want to have the program consider the orientation of the boxes in the calculations. How could I do this?

This is my code currently:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>

  //////////////////////////    
 // Zachary Holmes ICS3U //
//////////////////////////

// This program determines the number of boxes that can fit into a truck

// Declaring box size in centimetres
var boxHeightCm = prompt("What is the height of your box in centimetres?");
var boxWidthCm = prompt("What is the width of your box in centimetres?");
var boxLengthCm = prompt("What is the length of your box in centimetres?");

// Declaring truck size in metres
var truckHeight = prompt("What is the height of your truck in metres?");
var truckWidth = prompt("What is the width of your truck in metres?");
var truckLength = prompt("What is the length of your truck in metres?");

// Converting box size to metres
var boxHeight = boxHeightCm / 100;
var boxWidth = boxWidthCm / 100;
var boxLength = boxLengthCm / 100;

// Declaring variables used in equation
var boxVolume = boxHeight * boxWidth * boxLength;
var truckVolume = truckHeight * truckWidth * truckLength;

// Calculations
var boxNumberUnrounded = truckVolume / boxVolume;
var boxNumber = boxNumberUnrounded.toFixed(0);

// Output answer
alert(boxNumber);

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want us to do your homework?

Calculate how many boxes can be stacked in each direction (divide dimensions, truncate), then multiply these three numbers for total amount of boxes. Do not use volumes.

Comment: I have already finished this code...
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51454/simplified-bin-packing-using-javascript

Comment: Can you share your solution?

Comment: Cool. I'd probably delete this question then if no answer is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have improved the functionality and the logical process in the code here:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51454/simplified-bin-packing-using-javascript